# Parent redirect after click submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have Main page has some form elements and after clicking the submit. It should redirect the "search.php" page with $_POST Parameters;

My code given below

```
 <form name="form1" id="form1" action="search.php" method="POST"/>
       <input type="radio" id="domestic" name="select" value="domestic"/>
       <input type="submit" id="search" value="Search"/>
    </form>

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#search").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

                  var obj = $('#form1').serialize();
              $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                 url:"search.php",
                 data:obj,          
                success:function(data){
                  alert(obj);
                  // parent.tb_remove();
                  window.location.href ="search.php";
                             } //success
                }); 

        });
    });
```

search.php

```
echo $_REQUEST['obj'];
```

After ajax submit , It redirecr to search.php page, But  it didn't had the post value that i have sent from client side? How to pass parameters from client side to server side , with out pass by parameters ?

It is a pop up page i am using light box plugin.Main page has in popup and  after click search i need to close the light box and redirect parent link with new link

Comment: May I ask why you do an AJAX call and redirect, instead of just letting the browser to the normal thing which is to go to the URL in the `action` attribute of the form?

Comment: I am try to call lightbox popup above page

Comment: About which page and with which content?

Comment: Main Page is happened is in Popup, And it should redirect another normal page search.php

Comment: So do it with a normal POST/GET request instead of using jQuery for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a POST request and go there with that. If you really wan't to, you should use a GET request instead, and avoid the Ajax part.

Also, I don't get the point of doing what you want, since you are really "submitting" that form. Just submit it!

Answer (score 0):

i have to guess but sometimes i am good with it ;-)

1)

```
var obj = $('#form1').serialize();
```

if you have input elements with names like, "firstname", "lastname" this function will convert this into a string like that:

```
"firstname=VALUEOFINPUTHERE&lastname=VALUEOFINPUTHERE"
```

2)

```
function(data){
   alert(obj);
   // parent.tb_remove();
   window.location.href ="search.php";
 }
```

That alert cant work. obj is not defined inside that function. Use alert(data);

3) `echo $_REQUEST['obj'];`

There is no param obj that is passed to your page, obj is just the name of the javascript variable, the real data is (as said above) `firstname=VALUEOFINPUTHERE&lastname=VALUEOFINPUTHERE`

So you should either try `print_r($_REQUEST);` or `echo $_REQUEST['firstname'];`

Regards

PS: Pls let me know if i guessed right ;)